jq - difference in behavior between Linux and Windows version
Using jq 1.7 in Linux and Windows.  The following run fine in Linux (version 5.10.228-219.884.amzn2.x86_64), but gives error "'.[]' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" in Windows 11 command prompt or Powershell:
aws dms describe-replication-tasks --filter Name=replication-task-id,Values=TASKNAME --output json | jq '.ReplicationTasks | .[] | .TableMappings |= fromjson | .ReplicationTaskSettings |= fromjson | delpaths([ ["ReplicationTaskArn"],["ReplicationTaskStartDate"],["ReplicationTaskStats"],["Status"],["StopReason"],["ReplicationTaskCreationDate"],["ReplicationTaskSettings","Logging","CloudWatchLogGroup"],["ReplicationTaskSettings","Logging","CloudWatchLogStream"],["RecoveryCheckpoint"]]) | .TableMappings |= tostring |.ReplicationTaskSettings |= tostring' > TASKNAME.json

I've tried various tweaks, like replacing the ticks with quotes, but nothing seems to get this to run on Windows.
I expected the Windows command to produce the same output file as the Linux command did.

It's not jq behavior that's different -- it's shell behavior. The shell isn't recognizing ' as starting a quoted string, so it sees a | that you mean to use to separate jq operations as starting a whole new command, so it (the shell, not jq) tries to run .[] as a separate executable.

Consequently, this should tagged as either a cmd.exe question or a powershell question, not a jq question -- right now you're getting the wrong audience to understand the problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-azure-cli-successfully-quoting is probably a good place to start (it's not actually azure-specific)

Thanks - I added cmd and powershell (left jq for now).

Of cmd or powershell, if you were to pick only one, which one would you prefer a working answer for? (Personally, I'm positioned to test an answer for powershell, since it's available on non-Windows platforms, but not for cmd).

Mind, the other and perhaps more important thing is that we don't get the exact error you state on powershell -- you might think you tested there, but afaict you only checked cmd.

(were you maybe starting a .bat script from powershell when you tested? That won't work -- you need to save your file as a powershell script, meaning a .ps1 extension)

I am writing up a procedure for my team to use to export all of our AWS DMS tasks to json files that can be edited and migrated to another account.  The command I showed is adapted from https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/dms-backup-task-cli-jq.  My whole team has access to Windows' cmd, so I was hoping to get the solution working with that.  Our environment does have powershell, but I am much more famiiar with cmd.

If you won't accept an answer for any shell except cmd, you shouldn't tag the question with any shell except cmd

Single quotes do not act as quoting characters in cmd.exe. Since you specify in the question that PowerShell is an option, use it -- your jq command works perfectly there.
